# Android: Install released version of app to device from Eclipse

Tags: android, release, apk

When I want to compile a released version of my app, I sign it and rename the apk file to include a version number in the filename. To launch the app on my device I use adb. Is there a way this can be done in Eclipse?

Another related issue: If I press Run (Ctrl-F11), Eclipse will compile my apk and run it on the device. If my project is called "My App", the file "My App.apk" gets generated. It would be nice if I could get Eclipse to generate a filename that has the same filename as my released version and then maybe Eclipse would also install it with the Run command. Is this possible?

Comment: The signatures of the debug and release versions are different, so the packages conflict and it requires user intervention.

Comment: Well just because the signatures are different, what does that have to do with the semantics of compiling and launching the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve all that is mentioned in your question using Ant.  You can also run an Ant command from Eclipse.

The following resources would be helpful:

- [Using Ant to automate building Android applications](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html)
- [Building and running from the command line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html)

Comment: So you're saying that with the current version of Eclipse and the Android SDK, there is no other way to install a released version of an apk file other than using ANT or using adb?

Comment: What I am saying is that the Ant environment is integrated with Eclipse, and you don't have to go outside of Eclipse to achieve that. You can have Ant targets for the tasks that you want to achieve and execute those tasks _from Eclipse_. Moreover, Eclipse (and ADT) is a development environment and installs debug version of the app by design (and with a reason too).

Answer (score 0):

This not currently customizable in Eclipse. If you need to automate it, use Ant. You can then start Ant tasks from Eclipse as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to make the command line option easier...

Create a top level directory. Copy adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll and AdbWinUsbApi.dll into this, plus .apk. Then you can do this...

C:\Users\your_username>CD top

C:\Users\your_username\top>adb -d install yourapp.apk